# Table View Reloading Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have subclassed the a text view, that fires off a delegate method, when the height has changed.  When the height has changed I want to reload the table view cell, and increase its size

I am having one issue that I can not solve, the keyboard dismisses when the table view is reloaded, and I can not get around this.  Below is the delegate method that is called when the text view's height is changed.  Any suggestions?

```
- (void)textViewHeightChanged:(CGFloat)height
{
    if (height > _textViewCellHeight) {
        _textViewCellHeight = height;
        [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the text view is resigning first responder status. So you could try sending it `-becomeFirstResponder` after the table reload happens

Comment: @RichTolley I think that appeared to work, do you want to mark that as an answer, and i'll accept it in a few

Comment: is textView inside the table cell or how is it related to table ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableview is probably causing the textview to resign first responder status when it reloads. Try sending `-becomeFirstResponder` to your textview after the table reload happens.